# How to Convert a nested list with strings to a list with strings and ints

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

This is My current output for a Grocery list Code. The list is setup to find the sum of all of the items below. The structure of the list is

```
["Name", "Item Name", Item Amount, item Cost]

[['Emerie', 'keyboard', '29', '199'], ['Bodie', 'keyboard', '9', '199'], ['Emerie', 'bed', '1', '199'], ['Brecken', 'smartwatch', '9', '199'], ['Brecken', 'SSD', '9', '199']]
```

How can I get my output to look like this:

```
[['Emerie', 'keyboard', 29, 199], ['Bodie', 'keyboard', 9, 199], ['Emerie', 'bed', 1, 199], ['Brecken', 'smartwatch', 9, 199], ['Brecken', 'SSD', 9, 199]]
```

So The strings are strings and the ints are ints

*****This list is a dynamic list that is subject to change.*****

I tried many methods but none seem to work

Comment: A list that changes every time and may not necessarily be the same format @j1-lee

Comment: Sorry i meant different Entries, my bad...

Answer (score 1):

List comphrehension

```
a = [['Emerie', 'keyboard', '29', '199'], ['Bodie', 'keyboard', '9', '199'], ['Emerie', 'bed', '1', '199'], ['Brecken', 'smartwatch', '9', '199'], ['Brecken', 'SSD', '9', '199']]
[[int(j) if j.decimal() else j for j in i ] for i in a]
```

**output**

```
[['Emerie', 'keyboard', 29, 199],
 ['Bodie', 'keyboard', 9, 199],
 ['Emerie', 'bed', 1, 199],
 ['Brecken', 'smartwatch', 9, 199],
 ['Brecken', 'SSD', 9, 199]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension,

```
In [1]: [[int(j) if j.isdigit() else j for j in i] for i in l]
Out[1]: 
[['Emerie', 'keyboard', 29, 199],
 ['Bodie', 'keyboard', 9, 199],
 ['Emerie', 'bed', 1, 199],
 ['Brecken', 'smartwatch', 9, 199],
 ['Brecken', 'SSD', 9, 199]]
```

Comment: `isdigit()` can return true on some strings that will raise an exception when passed to `int()`. Maybe doesn't matter for the OP's use case, but may for future readers.